# Apache-Karate dependency causing errors with Springboot 2.1.1 webmvc controller tests

Tags: spring-boot, karate

For whatever reason, I suspect since apache-karate brings in httpclient, whenever I add the apache-karate dependency to my POM it breaks my Spring WebMVC Controller tests.

I get the following stacktrace (which I have already googled for):

> Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ValueExtractorManager
```

A snippet of my WebConfiguration is this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
```

So I know it's not how the application is configured. The two Karate dependencies I have ARE scoped to `test`.

Since it seems to be a dependency issue to me does anyone else have experience juggling these dependencies in order to get the `WebMvcTest` classes that tests controllers to work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ideally you should solve this by doing some `exclusion` hackery in your `pom.xml`.

Actually you can try swapping `karate-apache` with `karate-jersey` - the reason we have this option is to solve for this exact kind of dependency conflict hell, and this is mentioned in the documentation.

If you still face problems, follow this process and we can take a look: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: This worked in Intellij but failed in Jenkins. Maybe because Intellij is better are running the controller tests silo'ed?? I've created an issue using your link anyway as Jenkins lives matter :-D. I'm playing around with the karate-jersey dependencies but no luck yet.

Comment: @user11475606 and OSS maintainers lives matter more :P I have replied to your issue and closed it

Comment: I wasn't trying to be passive-agressive but I know that can be a default of developers. I have a proper user account on stackoverflow but I've been forced to create a new user because of my current client. I'm sorry my issue wasn't created correctly. Karate is a great abstraction that's needed over Cucumber. Glad you've stepped up. I fixed my issue by searching through the github issues for Karate. Found a case where someone upgraded from 0.9.1 to 0.9.2 and got the same problem as me, I downgraded to 0.9.1 and now it works. I also tried putting in 12 exclusions but that did not work.

Comment: @user11475606 peace. can you point me to the issue ? pretty sure the javafx dependency causes this - it seems to bring in a boatload of dependencies :| I will consider making that an optional separate module - https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/656

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure that's it. I put in close to 12 exclusions for karate-jersey including the javafx. The error of NoClassDefFound comes all the way from some hibernate class when it runs in Jenkins. Here's the issue that helped me: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/733

Comment: @user11475606 pretty sure that has to be it: https://github.com/intuit/karate/compare/v0.9.1...master#diff-600376dffeb79835ede4a0b285078036R67 - nothing else was changed. anyway I think the extra maven module is the right call - will work on it

Comment: Fair enough! I'll try excluding just that dependency again and see what happens. Of course it would be a Hibernate class that acts up...

Comment: @user11475606 can you try now with 0.9.3.RC2 ?